# Pass arg to function

Tags: python, python-3.x, argv

how do i pass an arg `10 9 - 5 +`, and receive an answer `6` through the command line? I have a function, but I'm not sure how to pass arguments to it in order to make it work.

This is the function:

```
def polish_calc():
    polish = "10 9 - 5 +"
    print(int(polish[:2]) - int(polish[-7]) + int(polish[-3]))
polish_calc()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a script `some_script.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
print sys.argv
```

Then you could call it like so:

```
$ python some_script.py hello world
['some_script.py', 'hello', 'world']
```

For reverse Polish notation, you'll want to split your strings into tokens and use a stack to hold them.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [sys.argv](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.argv). 
For adding more arguments check the [argparse](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/argparse.html) module. It has some cool argument parsing functions.

You can put this in a script foo.py

```
#foo.py
import sys
def polish_calc(polish):
    print(int(polish[:2]) - int(polish[-7]) + int(polish[-3]))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        script_arg = sys.argv[1]
        polish_calc(script_arg)
```

To call it, you can do

```
 > foo.py "10 9 - 5 +"
 > 6
```

Comment: Thank you, so sys.argv[1] call the function? what is script_arg? is it build in function?

Comment: no sys.argv is a list of arguments to the script. sys.argv[1] is the second element. script_arg is the variable name.